# Add name of each directory to files inside the corresponding directory in linux

Tags: linux, loops, directory, file-rename, batch-rename

I have a directory containing multiple directories. here is an example of the list of directories:

- dir1_out
- dir2_out
- dir3_out
- dir4_out

Each directory contains multiple files. 
For example folder1_out contains the following files:

- file1
- file2
- file3

In the same fashion other directories contain several folders. 
I would like to add the name of each directory to file name in the corresponding directory. 
I would like to have the following result in first directory(dir1_out):

```
  dir1.file1
  dir1.file2
  dir1.file3
```

Since I have around 50 directories I would like to write a loop that takes the name of each directory and add the name to the beginning of all subfiles.

Do you have any idea how can I do that in linux.

Comment: What's the maximum number of characters in your directory and file names? Generally, this is doable but if names are long, on some filesystems you could exceed the path limits (255 character max is common).

Comment: maximum number of characters in directory and file names is 45 and 20  respectively.

Comment: No problem hitting MAXPATHLEN then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple bash onliner if there aren't too many files is:

```
for p in */*; do [ -f "$p" ] && mv -i "$p" "${p%/*}/${p/\//.}"; done
```

This uses parameter expansions to generate new filenames, after checking that we are trying to rename an actual file - See bash manpage descriptions of `${parameter%word}` and `${parameter/pattern/string}`

If there may be too many files to safely expand them all into a single list:

```
#!/bin/bash
find . -maxdepth 2 -print |\
while read p; do
    p="${p#./}"
    mv -i "$p" "${p%/*}/${p/\//.}"
done
```